# How to ad iphone event from windows app? Is this possible at all?

Tags: java, iphone, contacts, icalendar

I have a local windows app written in java, kind of crm.
Employees register events, like customer future calls, visits, meetings, etc.

1. I would like to pass these events from windows app to their iphones, so they see the reminder. The information should be registered in windows app, not on the iphone. 
   Is it possible somehow? I would like to avoid writing and app on iphone.
2. Is this possible to access address book in similar way? Let's say that Mr A is account manager for 30 customers. I would like to sync their contacts data stored in windows app with his iphone.

Is this possible in the way that it is windows app which synchronizes the data, not the app on iphone?

Thanks in advance
Brgs
Norbert

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) especially the "how to ask questions" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to interact with an iPhone from your Windows PC, without having to create an app for the iPhone? If this is the case, I don;t know that this is possible.

To send an alert to an iPhone, there is the ability to send a Push Notification from an external source (such as your Windows PC/app) onto an iPhone. This is what happens in your mail apps on your iPhone - when you get an email on your email server, it sends a Push Notification to your iPhone telling it that there is a new email to read. However, to support Push Notifications, you need to have an app on the iPhone that knows what to do with it. In other words, you will still need an app on the iPhone so that when it receives a Push Notification from your Windows app, it knows that it should display a message to the iPhone user.

As far as I know, there isn't any way to retrieve information from an iPhone from an external source without having an app on the phone. This would be a pretty bad security concern if it were possible.

Accessing or syncing contacts will also need an app on the iPhone that can interact with the contacts and send them back-forth to your windows app.

You *may* be able to interact with contacts on an iPhone if you have it plugged in via USB. The USB provides a direct connection to the phone, so if you wrote the write Windows socket code then you should be able to talk to the iPhone over the USB and perform some tasks on there. However, I'm not sure whether you can interact with Contacts and other phone information - it is probable that you could only interact with files stored on the phone such as music and videos?

Don't be scared to write an app to do what you want - especially for alerting the user, it is a pretty simple app to write, as it doesn't need to do much processing, doesn't need to have any user interface at all, and all the Push Notification support is already built in to standard iOS libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

> If I understand correctly, you are wanting to interact with 
> an iPhone from your Windows PC, without having to create 
> an app for the iPhone?

Yes, this is the goal.

I googled a bit for the Push notifications and indeed it seems to be very interesting and maybe the only one possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do if your windows app allows you to is to add those events to outlook calendar and then use the google sync to push those events to a google calendar which is then added in the user iphone. the reminder would then be a iphone calendar reminder. no security leak but little control on the iphone side about reminders.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but it is not an option for me. 
I don't want to use outlook at all.